# Building my Next JS application is failing when building static pages using Strapi data (prerender-error)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

I am building a website for my podcast network and while everything is working as expected in development, when I build the application for production, the build fails when building static pages, seemingly from gathering data from my Strapi backend. The pages are individual [slug].js pages for each cast member and for each show (though it appears to be failing only for the show pages).

**Here is the code for the [slug].js:**

```
import React from "react"
import Image from "next/image"
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid"
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography"
import Chip from "@mui/material/Chip"

import GMCard from "../../src/components/GMCard"
import PlayerCard from "../../src/components/PlayerCard"

import { fetchAPI } from "../../lib/api"
import { getStrapiMedia } from "../../lib/media"

const Game = ({ game, characters, people }) => {
  let players = []
  let pcs = []

  const gameMaster = people.filter(
    (person) => person.id === game.attributes.gameMaster.data.id
  )

  game.attributes.players.data.forEach((player) => {
    const filtered = people.filter((person) => player.id === person.id)
    players.push(filtered.pop())
  })

  game.attributes.characters.data.forEach((pc) => {
    const filtered = characters.filter((char) => pc.id === char.id)
    pcs.push(filtered.pop())
  })

  return (
    <Grid container direction="column">
      <Grid item>
        <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="center">
          <Grid item sx={{ marginBottom: "3rem" }}>
            <Typography variant="h1">Our Games and Shows</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item sx={{ marginBottom: "3rem" }}>
            <Typography variant="h2">{game.attributes.name}</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container justifyContent="center">
            <Grid item sx={{ marginBottom: "3rem", marginLeft: "3rem" }}>
              <Image
                src={getStrapiMedia(game.attributes.image)}
                alt={`${game.attributes.name} logo`}
                style={{ height: "25rem" }}
              ></Image>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item sx={{ marginBottom: "3rem", marginLeft: "3rem" }}>
              <Grid container direction="column" sx={{ width: "50rem" }}>
                <Grid item>
                  <Typography variant="h2">{game.attributes.system}</Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                  {game.attributes.season1 ? (
                    <Chip
                      label={"Season 1"}
                      sx={{
                        padding: 0,
                        marginRight: "0.5rem",
                        marginBottom: "0.5rem",
                        color: "#ffffff",
                        backgroundColor: "green",
                      }}
                    />
                  ) : null}
                  {game.attributes.season2 ? (
                    <Chip
                      label={"Season 2"}
                      sx={{
                        padding: 0,
                        marginRight: "0.5rem",
                        marginBottom: "0.5rem",
                        color: "#000000",
                        backgroundColor: "#ffff00",
                      }}
                    />
                  ) : null}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                  <Typography variant="body1">
                    {game.attributes.description}
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="center">
            <Grid item sx={{ marginBottom: "3rem" }}>
              <Typography variant="h2">Game Master</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item sx={{ marginBottom: "3rem" }}>
              <Grid container direction="column">
                <Grid item>
                  <GMCard person={gameMaster[0]} />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="center">
            <Grid item sx={{ marginBottom: "3rem" }}>
              <Typography variant="h2">Players</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container justifyContent="center">
              {players.map((player) => {
                const pc = pcs.filter(
                  (char) => char.attributes.player.data.id === player.id
                )
                return (
                  <Grid item key={`char_${player.id}`}>
                    <PlayerCard person={player} character={pc[0]} />
                  </Grid>
                )
              })}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const gamesres = await fetchAPI("/games", { fields: ["slug"] })

  return {
    paths: gamesres.data.map((game) => ({
      params: {
        slug: game.attributes.slug,
      },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const [peopleRes] = await Promise.all([
    fetchAPI("/people", { populate: "*" }),
  ])
  const [charactersRes] = await Promise.all([
    fetchAPI("/characters", { populate: "*" }),
  ])
  const gamesRes = await fetchAPI("/games", {
    filters: {
      slug: params.slug,
    },
    populate: "*",
  })

  return {
    props: {
      game: gamesRes.data[0],
      characters: charactersRes.data,
      people: peopleRes.data,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  }
}

export default Game
```

**GMCard.js:**

```
import React from "react"
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid"
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography"
import Card from "@mui/material/Card"
import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions"
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent"
import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia"
import Button from "@mui/material/Button"

import { getStrapiMedia } from "../../lib/media"

import ArrowForwardIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowForward"

const GMCard = ({ person }) => {
  return (
    <Grid item sx={{ margin: "1rem" }}>
      <Card
        sx={{
          width: 400,
          minHeight: 400,
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
        }}
      >
        <CardMedia
          sx={{ height: 400 }}
          image={getStrapiMedia(person.attributes.headshot)}
          title={`${person.attributes.lastName} headshot`}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="h3" component="div">
            {`${person.attributes.firstName} ${person.attributes.lastName}`}
          </Typography>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h4" component="div">
              {`Game Master`}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions sx={{ justifyContent: "flex-end", marginTop: "auto" }}>
          <Button
            href={`/about/${person.attributes.slug}`}
            endIcon={<ArrowForwardIcon />}
          >
            Bio
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default GMCard
```

**PlayerCard.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Image from "next/image"
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid"
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography"
import Card from "@mui/material/Card"
import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions"
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent"
import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia"
import Button from "@mui/material/Button"
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal"

import { getStrapiMedia } from "../../lib/media"

import ArrowForwardIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowForward"

const PlayerCard = ({ person, character }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true)
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false)

  return (
    <Grid item sx={{ margin: "1rem" }}>
      <Card
        sx={{
          width: 400,
          minHeight: 400,
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
        }}
      >
        <CardMedia
          sx={{ height: 400 }}
          image={getStrapiMedia(person.attributes.headshot)}
          title={`${person.attributes.lastName} headshot`}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="h3" component="div">
            {`${person.attributes.firstName} ${person.attributes.lastName} as`}
          </Typography>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h3" component="div">
              {`${character.attributes.name}`}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions sx={{ justifyContent: "flex-end", marginTop: "auto" }}>
          <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="flex-end">
            <Button
              href={`/about/${person.attributes.slug}`}
              endIcon={<ArrowForwardIcon />}
            >
              Bio
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={handleOpen} endIcon={<ArrowForwardIcon />}>
              Character Info
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
      <Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Grid container direction="column">
          <Grid
            item
            sx={{
              position: "absolute",
              top: "50%",
              left: "50%",
              transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
              width: 600,
              bgcolor: "background.paper",
              border: "2px solid #000",
              boxShadow: 24,
              p: 4,
            }}
          >
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item>
                <Image
                  src={getStrapiMedia(character.attributes.image)}
                  alt={`${character.attributes.name} art`}
                  style={{ height: 225, width: 225 }}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Grid
                  container
                  direction="column"
                  justifyContent="space-between"
                  sx={{ height: 225, marginLeft: "0.5rem" }}
                >
                  <Grid item>
                    <Grid container direction="column">
                      <Grid item>
                        <Typography variant="h3" component="div">
                          {`${character.attributes.name}`}
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                        <Typography variant="h4" component="div">
                          {`${character.attributes.role}`}
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                        <Button
                          href={`/team/${character.attributes.player.data.attributes.slug}`}
                          sx={{
                            textTransform: "none",
                            padding: 0,
                            color: "#000",
                          }}
                        >
                          {`Played by ${character.attributes.player.data.attributes.firstName} ${character.attributes.player.data.attributes.lastName}`}
                        </Button>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item>
                    <Grid container direction="column">
                      <Grid item>
                        <Typography
                          variant="h3"
                          component="div"
                          sx={{
                            color: "#000",
                          }}
                        >
                          {`${character.attributes.game.data.attributes.name}`}
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                        <Button
                          endIcon={<ArrowForwardIcon />}
                          sx={{ textTransform: "none", padding: 0 }}
                        >
                          {`About ${character.attributes.game.data.attributes.name}`}
                        </Button>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Typography variant="body1">
                {character.attributes.bio}
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Modal>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default PlayerCard
```

**And here's the errors:**

```
$ npm run build

> frontend@0.1.0 build
> next build

info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\.env
info  - Linting and checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully
Warning: You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to `getInitialProps` in `pages/_app`. This does not opt-out pages with `getStaticProps`
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/opt-out-auto-static-optimization

info  - Collecting page data
[==  ] info  - Generating static pages (0/45)
Error occurred prerendering page "/games/call-of-the-deep". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\.next\server\pages\games\[slug].js:212:109
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\.next\server\pages\games\[slug].js:212:52
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Game (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\.next\server\pages\games\[slug].js:211:51)
    at Wc (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)

Error occurred prerendering page "/games/the-academy". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')
    at C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\.next\server\pages\games\[slug].js:212:72
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\.next\server\pages\games\[slug].js:212:52
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Game (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\.next\server\pages\games\[slug].js:211:51)
    at Wc (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)

// ...repeating errors for each page

info  - Generating static pages (45/45)

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /games/[slug]: /games/a-walk-among-gods
        /games/[slug]: /games/brave-new-wild
        /games/[slug]: /games/call-of-the-deep
        /games/[slug]: /games/duskvale
        /games/[slug]: /games/friday-night-fights
        /games/[slug]: /games/furusato
        /games/[slug]: /games/heckna
        /games/[slug]: /games/neon-memories
        /games/[slug]: /games/nights-of-payne-town
        /games/[slug]: /games/red-harvest
        /games/[slug]: /games/tavern-tales
        /games/[slug]: /games/the-academy
        /games/[slug]: /games/the-crystal-city
        /games/[slug]: /games/the-hunt-for-glory
    at C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:409:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1345:21
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1205:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (C:\Users\gmrpr\Desktop\Code_Projects\VibeTribe\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:66:29)
```

Let me know if there is any more info you need, but I could use all the help I can get. I'm out of ideas.